# Как задать расстояние между "строками" flexbox?

Tags: css, css3, html5, flexbox

Как указать расстояние между строками?

```
.uploader-file-system-panel-scroll{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как вы хотите регулировать, то только с помощью `margin` и `padding`

Но есть у флексов `align-content`, который позволяет распределять элементы по всему флекс-контейнеру или только по центру.

[Подробнее на эту тему](http://css-live.ru/articles/vizualnoe-rukovodstvo-po-svojstvam-flexbox-iz-css3.html)